# R: parse key/value pairs from a string

Tags: r, string, httpresponse

How do I parse a string of key/value pairs (such as a responder header) into a named character vector?

```
input <- "val1=A; val2=B; val3=C"
desired_output <- c(val1 = "A", val2 = "B", val3 = "C")
```

Answer (score 2):

I added two solutions, one based on regex and one on `parse` function. The parse solution requires the values to be quoted so it is an addition.

```r
input <- "val1=A; val2=B; val3=C"
input2 <- "val1='A'; val2='B'; val3='C'"
desired_output <- c(val1 = "A", val2 = "B", val3 = "C")

ee <- new.env()
eval(parse(text = input2), envir = ee)
output_1 <- unlist(as.list(ee))
identical(output_1, desired_output)
#> [1] TRUE

res <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(strsplit(gsub(" ", "", input), ";")[[1]], "="))
output_2 <- res[, 2]
names(output_2) <- res[, 1]
identical(output_2, desired_output)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>